# Overloading operator=, zero the pole

Tags: c++, class, overloading

In programm i have classes Player, Animation.

```
class Player
{
 ...
 Animation* currentAnimation;
 Animation anim1;
 Animation anim2;
 void Update(bool state);
 ...
 //when class is created, currentAnimation is initialized
}
void Player::Update(bool state)
{
   if(state) currentAnimation = &anim1;
   if(!state) currentAnimation = &anim2;
}
```

I need to zero out one of the fields when assigning. Like this:
currentAnimation = anim1;
anim1 should zero, for example, pole1.
I overloaded the assignment operator in the Animation class in this way:

```
Animation & Animation::operator=(Animation & anim)
{
    if (this != &anim)
    {
        //here other poles is assignmented
        //like this: this->pole2 = anim.pole2;
        ...
        anim.pole1 = 0;
        return *this;
    }
}
```

All is working but pole1 is not zero

Comment: Why would you modify `anim` in `operator=`? In fact I'd change the signature to `Animation& Animation::operator=(Animation const&)`. As a caller of your code I would be very startled to see that assigning to an object modifies the object you're assigning *from*

Comment: This would be more appropriate for a move assignment operator. [FWIW, though](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange)...

Comment: Notice that assigning a pointer of type `Animation *` doesn't call `Animation::operator=(...)`

Comment: First of all what is the Animation class looking like? Second I wonder if you actually mean this->pole1 = 0 instead.

Comment: If someone torched my notebook after making a copy of a lesson they missed, I'd be upset. Don't write mutating copy assignment operators, seriously.

Comment: @orhtej2 It feels to me that i`m wrong, and this is two different things. So how should i rewrite overloading to make it works with Animation*
The second thing, I understand that I should not modifiy the assigned object, but I think, for my problem, I should do such thing

Comment: @Nikita.L, You can't overload for pointers, and they already have built-in assignment. Anyway, you're going to run into all the same problems as `auto_ptr` did, and `auto_ptr` is completely gone now, replaced by the ability to have proper move semantics.